# OracleConfiguration.TnsAdmin not working?

Tags: .net, oracle, tnsnames, oracle.manageddataaccess

I downloaded Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core 2.19.1 for .Net.

At first, I tried **OracleConfiguration.OracleDataSources.Add()** and I was able to establish the connection.

I, then, tried to experiment with **OracleConfiguration.TnsAdmin** thinking if I can get this to work, I don't have to add the DataSources one by one (*we have a lot*).

Unfortunately, TnsAdmin did not work.  I got this error:
**ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified**

Am I missing something or this feature does not work?

P.S.  I tried to find the docs, but no luck.

Comment: If you have a lot of databases then you should consider the OID Oracle name service which provides the alias resolution in a central server.

Comment: Why not use the existing `tnsnames.ora` file? You can configure it like this `OraProvCfg /action:config /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /providerpath:c:\Oracle\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll /set:settings\TNS_ADMIN:c:\Oracle\network\admin` Program `OraProvCfg.exe` should be available in your Oracle folder.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit tns_admin is used by Oracle to point to a central folder where a "master" copy of tnsnames.ora is used, so the issue is not that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Oracle, there's a bug with OracleConfiguration that prevents TnsAdmin from using the hidden share in Windows, i.e. \server\share$.

The bug number is: 29956349